# Will javascript written on attribute onclick finished first before running the action?

Tags: javascript, jsf, onclick

I am using JSF on my project. 
My scenario is that I have a form with a lot of input fields, and before calling the action on the a4j:commandButton I will be converting the input fields into JSON Data using javascript. 
I haven't tested with a really large Form, my current form seems to be submitted correctly upon 'onclick'.

My question is would all of the javascript written on the attribute 'onclick' finish first before running the 'action'?

I've read some articles across the web and it says  that 
onclick = JavaScript code to be invoked before Ajax request is sent. 
However it does not say that it would finish all up the javascript before invoking 'action'

Could you clear this up for me?
Thanks!

Here's a sample code

```js
function transformToJson(object){
   //transform all input fields to json data
}
```

```html
<a4j:commandButton onclick="submitJsonObject(transformToJson('.myForm'))"
    value="Save"
    action="#{bean.save}">
</a4j:commandButton>


<a4j:jsFunction name="submitJsonObject">
    <a:actionparam name="param1" assignTo="#{model.jsonData}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

The submitJsonObject is a a4:jsFunction, it will send the jsondata into my model, would the transformToJson and submitJsonObject finish before actually invoking the action="#{bean.save}"?

Comment: Could you share some of the code you're discussing about?

Comment: Do you actually need to use jsf?

Comment: Hmm, yep, I need to , there are other save that will be ongoing on the save button, not just transferring the jsonData, I'm sorry that was not clear on the code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the browser should not submit any data at all before the `onclick` method returns, since returning false will signal the browser not to submit at all.

In all cases and frameworks i have seen the generated code will either use the browsers own internal submit, that is to say no additional code will be added to the `onclick` event **OR** append any required code after the user defined code in the `onclick` handler.

If in doubt use your browsers inspection tools, but its fairly safe to assume all code will be executed prior to submit.